# How to load last page of KendoGrid in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a set of data being displayed in kendoGrid and I am adding records in the grid using UI. Once a record is added I want to do two things:

1. Refresh Grid
2. Load the last page(because new record is always added last)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dataSource [`query`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound) on [`dataBound`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound) event:

```
grid.dataSource.query({ page: Math.floor(grid.dataSource.total/20 ), pageSize: 20 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Mozgovoy's answer got me close to what I needed in a similar scenario, but I found that using `Math.ceil()` worked better. Setting the page to `Math.floor()` rounded the result down, which would put me on the next to last grid page if I didn't have a whole number.